# How to access the node/term field-values in a cleaner way?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

My code is filled with methods like these to access field values:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->get('field_name')->getValue()[0]['value'];
\Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($tid)->get('field_name')->getValue()[0]['value'];
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->get('field_name')->getValue()[0]['value'];
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->get('field_entity')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')->get('field_link')->getValue()[0]['title'];
```

And in twig templates:

```
content.field_name[0]['#context']['value']
item.entity.field_tech_spec_name.0.value
item.entity.field_image_link.0.url
```

Surely there has to be a more correct and aesthetic way to get these, which I am missing. Sorry for such a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use magic getter methods like `$entity->field_name->database_column` to get the first value of a field:

```
$node->field_name->value;
$node->field_entity->target_id;
$node->field_link->title;
```

etc

This will get the first value of that field (and will not work with multi cardinality fields). If that is *"cleaner"*... there are people who claim magic getters are plain evil. A more practical downside is that your IDE's Intellisense/autocompletion will not work with magic getters.

Comment: is there any shorthand way to access them in twig templates?